# How does smashing a statue impact the odds that an object is hidden in one of the other statues in a set?

Tags: probability, statistics

The title is a bit confusing, I'm not sure of a better way to sum it up.

Let's say there is a group of 5 statues and a missing jewel. There's a 50% chance that the jewel is hidden in one of the 5 statues. This should mean that there's a 10% chance it's in each individual statue. If you smash one statue and prove that the jewel is not hidden in the one you smashed, do the odds that the jewel is in each of the other statues increase, because there are only 4 left? Or do they decrease, because the jewel wasn't in the one you smashed?

Comment: Just as an idea: you flip a coin before you make the experiment. now you smash a statue. Does the smashed statue change the result of your cointoss?

Comment: Btw, i think this topic will help you greatly, its the same problem basicly: https://www.reddit.com/r/riddles/comments/2618xm/forgetting_the_keys_probability_riddle/

Comment: But that's different. The statue can't affect the coin. In this case, one could argue that because the statue was smashed, the odds that it's in the statues at all now decreases. So are the odds still 10% that it's in each of the other statues? 12.5% because there's a 50% chance of it still being in the statues? 1/9 because the relative odds don't change? That link says the relative odds don't change, but I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: @saturatedexpo The relative odds do change, since the events "Jewel is in Statue 1" and "Jewel is in Statue 2" are not independent, as opposed to the events "Jewel is in Statue 2" and "I flipped tails".

Comment: I can’t resist noting that the biggest impact is on the smashed statue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The odds do in fact increase. For clarity imagine there are five other statues you can't see, and the jewel is actually hidden, with equal probability $\frac{1}{10}$, among all ten. Smashing one of the statues removes the possibility that the jewel is in that statue, so now the jewel must be hidden with equal probability $\frac{1}{9}$ among each of the remaining $9$ statues, and $\frac{1}{9} > \frac{1}{10}$.

So the odds that the jewel is in a specific other statue increase, however the odds that the jewel is hidden in a visible statue at all decreases from $\frac{5}{10}$ to $\frac{4}{9}$.